# Regex sublimetext replacement of a recurrent string in a text file after a specific string

Tags: regex, sublimetext, pcre

I've literally spent two full days searching here, on google and on regex101 before asking.
Here's what my files (thousands of them) look like:

```
FIRST LINE THAT MIGHT CONTAIN ON .
SECTION1
SOME TEXT THAT MIGHT CONTAIN ON .
SECTION2
ON 04/1/2017 SOME TEXT
ON 25/1/2017 SOME TEXT
ON 15/2/2017 SOME TEXT
```

I need to remove every `ON` occurrences in SECTION2 only.
I can't obviously post the patterns that didn't work over two days of trial and error. (It'd be flooding search engines with irrelevant stuff along with proving my limited wits - on the subject matter that is ;-)

Comment: Is there a `SECTION3` or after `SECTION2`'s contents the file os over?

Comment: There's no SECTION3. That's pretty much the template of the files. (although I've been considering adding a "tag" at the end of each file but I won't be able to verify all of them, it has to be fail-safe)

Comment: If you are sure those ONs of SECTION2 are always at the start of the line (and SECTION1 and others' aren't) you could use `^ON `.

Comment: Thanks! So simple I understand the downvotes now... Slight drawback though. It just realized I do have ONs at the beginig of the first line on some files... (actually they are not ONs but LEs which occur on some french last names that constitute the first line, gasp... Got it working like so ftr: `(?<=\n).*(^LE )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\A(?>.*\R)*?SECTION2\h*\R)(?>.*\R)*?\KON\h
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/ClLli4/1)

The idea is to build a pattern that can only returns contiguous matches using the `\G` anchor. This anchor succeeds at the beginning of the string or at the position after a successful match.

Pattern details:

```
(?: # non-capturing group: two possible starts
    \G(?!\A)  # the position after a previous match
  |           # OR
    \A(?>.*\R)*?SECTION2\h*\R # reach the first occurrence of SECTION2 from the start
)
(?>.*\R)*? # match lazily eventual lines that don't start with ON
\K         # remove all on the left from the match result
ON\h       # and keep only ON with a trailing space
```

`(?!\A)` forbids the first branch to succeed at the start of the string, this way the first match uses always the second branch (only one time since it starts with `\A`). The next matches use always the first branch. This forces all the occurrences of ON to be after SECTION2.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you soooo much. And thanks for the explanations as well. Massive gloubiboulga to you ;-)
(such a relief my spine actually cracked)